# Why is my updated input not being submitted with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

I have some text inputs that have a default value of "color." When a user clicks a button, that value is replaced by a hex value pulled out of a color picker. When I try to submit the form via AJAX, the input value is reset back to "color." Why is this happening? FYI, the inputs are disabled so users can't enter alternate text.

HTML

```
<table id="lbltbl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl1"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c1" id="clr1" value="color1" disabled="disabled" /></p>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl2"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c2" id="clr2" value="color2" disabled="disabled" /></p>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl3"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c3" id="clr3" value="color3" disabled="disabled" /></p>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl4"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c4" id="clr4" value="color4" disabled="disabled" /></p>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl5"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c5" id="clr5" value="color5" disabled="disabled" /></p>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl6"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c6" id="clr6" value="color6" disabled="disabled" /></p>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl7"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c7" id="clr7" value="color7" disabled="disabled" /></p>
            <p class="lbls" id="lbl8"><input class="lab" type="text" name="c8" id="clr8" value="color8" disabled="disabled" /></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('input.lab').each(function(index) {
    $('button#btn' + (index + 1)).on('click', function() {
        $('input#clr' + (index + 1)).val('#' + $('div.colorpicker_hex').children().val());
    });
});

$.ajax ({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'classes/requests/addRequest.php',
    data: {
        c1: $('#clr1').val()
    }
```

Comment: Unless you show code, how can anyone tell you what's wrong?

Comment: Disabled control value is not submitted in form. it will be appreciated if you paste some script you are using..

Comment: You are binding event, not setting its value. `$('button#btn' + (index + 1)).on('click', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without seeing the code but I would guess that your JS isn't selecting the element correctly to account for the DOM elements loaded after the initial load.

Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: this should be in comment

Answer (score 0):

i m' not sure as your code is still incomplete, but as per W3 standards disabled control's value is not submitted in form. Look at this [W3 Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled)

If you want that user doesn't change value explicitly you can mark control as readonly.